# has the 8060 bytes per row limitation been adjusted in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Due to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnts/archive/2006/12/01/row-size-limitation-in-sql-2000-and-2005.aspx) issue, select tables in our db have a fixed row size although we need more.

Has this been fixed in SQL Server 2008 Express? 
Where can I get the details?

For best performance, what is the best way to handle large row sizes in SQL Server 2008 Express?

Comment: This is a very fundamental mainstay of SQL Server's architecture, and it's highly unlikely this will be *"fixed"* any time soon .....

Comment: thx all for your comments and suggestions on this. Very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ~8K page size [still exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186981.aspx), however it is mitigated for some types with the use of  [`MAX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178158.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Personally I usually prefer to create a second table that has a one to one relationship with the first table and put the extra columns there. It is best if you can keep the most used columns in the first table and the least used in the related table.

Answer (score 2):

The issue does still exist.

The best way to handle very wide rows like this is to normalize your data so you break them up into multiple tables.  If you have one or two very wide fields, move them to another table and `JOIN` to that table if you need that data.